# ls command inside Vim is showing a weird result

Tags: vim

When trying to save a file in vim I used the ls command to see the folder I want to save in. 
I got the following output after using the ls command:

[image: 1 %a + "[No Name]" line 1]

Obviously that's not the contents of the folder. 
Can anyone tell me why that's happening and how to fix it?
Thanks :)

Comment: Type `:help ls` and you will know ;) Tip: To execute shell commands, prepend them with `!`.

Answer (score 19):

Try these two commands

```
:help :ls
:!ls
```

Comment: See @ISQ's answer for the "why," or, as @Felix suggested, try `:help ls`.

Answer (score 18):

`:!ls` is a call to ls command in the shell == list of your files in the working dir.

`:ls`  is a Vim built-in command, which shows content of buffer list == list of your open files.

Answer (score 0):

Each buffer has a unique number. Use this number to call the buffer.

```
:ls
```

```
1    "/test/test"             line 1
3    "/another_test/test2"    line 0
12   "/test/test3"            line 1
```

```
:b 12
```

or

```
:buffer 12
```